# How to fix an Error in creating a xamarin project in visual studio

Tags: android, xamarin, android-ndk, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have just installed visual studio 2015 and then I installed Xamarin for it on win10. The problem happens when I want to create an android project

```
A problem was encountered creating the sub project 'App8.Droid'.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

[image]

Android has been installed correctly:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Can you try to install Jdk1.8 ?

Comment: my internet connection speed is low, but I will try

Comment: You may also try to update Android SDKs in Android SDK Manager

Comment: I installed Jdk 1.8 and the problemm didn't solve
what version of sdk should i install?

Comment: May be Xamarin guys can answer that. I have not experienced that problem, sorry

Comment: I updated JDK and to 1.8 and SDK tools to 24.4.1
the problem still exists

Answer (score 0):

This might be this bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=40781

If so, try deleting the VS ComponentModelCache at

C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

and then restart VS. If that alone does not help, also try deleting the temp directory at:

C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: I deleted both of them and the problem didn't solved